# Why is JavaScript treating windows 10 pro, IE11 as mobile or tablet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I do not have mobile / tablet compatible layout, so when any user comes from mobile/tablet/linux terminal, I show a page "get out". But if the user is coming from a PC browsers IE old, IE edge, Safari, Google Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Midori etc etc. Then it is allowed.

Why am I getting `is_pc` as `false` even the browser was PC and IE11?

```
window.onload = userAgentDetect;
var is_pc = true;
function userAgentDetect() {
  if(window.navigator.userAgent.match(/Mobile/i)
  || window.navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
  || window.navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
  || window.navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i)
  || window.navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)
  || window.navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
  || window.navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
  || window.navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)) {
    document.body.className+=' mobile';
    is_pc = false;
    get_out_from_here();
  } 

  if(window.navigator.userAgent.match(/Tablet/i)
  || window.navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)
  || window.navigator.userAgent.match(/Nexus 7/i)
  || window.navigator.userAgent.match(/Nexus 10/i)
  || window.navigator.userAgent.match(/KFAPWI/i)) {
    document.body.className-=' mobile';
    document.body.className+=' tablet';
    is_pc = false;
    get_out_from_here();
  } 
}
```

Comment: If you debug it, you should get your answer...  `console.log(window.navigator.userAgent)`

Comment: Whats wrong with feature detection? / or responsive website?..  Checking the usageAgent is meant to be bad practice, and can always be faked anyway.

Comment: Sir, window.navigator.userAgent prints: `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; Touch; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; Tablet PC 2.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko`

Comment: Do you see the word Tablet in there?

Comment: btw.  `document.body.className -= ' mobile';`  I don't think will do what you expect, unless you want `NaN` as the className.. try  `document.body.classList.remove('mobile')`

Comment: `Tablet PC 2.0;`  is showing but will that same word also have in real world iPad, Android tablets too?

Comment: can you please update the method, so that its compatible function for real world tablets, mobile only, but ignores all the real world pc web-browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working.

```
window.onload = userAgentDetect;
var is_pc = true;
function userAgentDetect() {
  if(window.navigator.userAgent.match(/Mobile/i)
  || window.navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
  || window.navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
  || window.navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i)
  || window.navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)
  || window.navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
  || window.navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
  || window.navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)) {
    document.body.className+=' mobile';
    is_pc = false;
    get_out_from_here();
  } 

  if(window.navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)
  || window.navigator.userAgent.match(/Nexus 7/i)
  || window.navigator.userAgent.match(/Nexus 10/i)
  || window.navigator.userAgent.match(/KFAPWI/i)) {
    document.body.className-=' mobile';
    document.body.className+=' tablet';
    is_pc = false;
    get_out_from_here();
  } 
}
```